# Applying a Logarithmic Animation

Tags: jquery, objective-c, c, animation

In Psuedocode, if I have object that I wish to transform in a non linear fashion based on some delta range from 0 to 1.

How can I apply concepts such as Ease in / Ease out?

Essentially I'm wanting the object to start animating in slowly but begin to accelerate until it reaches the desired location at delta = 1.

So a Logarithmic animation.

For example:

```
Delta = Delta* function(x)

object.transform = Do Something with the Delta.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have the animation divided into `N` equal steps in time `T`, `Delta = (t - t0)/T`.

If you do a linear speed transformation you would choose frame `N * Delta` at time `t`.

To apply ease in/ease out you want to swap frame slower in the beginning and end and faster in the middle.

You could hand-code the speed function or use something with appropriate behaviour. `sin` is a function that could work for you. You need to scale it, since it goes from `-1` to `+1` in the range `-PI/2` to `PI/2`.

```
frame_number(t) = (int) (N * 0.5*(1 + sin(PI*(Delta-0.5)))
```